# Thread objectoutputstream objectinputstream blocking not reading

Tags: java, concurrency, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream, concurrenthashmap

My code is ill; what looks like a fairly straightforward object write and read operation, never seems to fire its secondary operations. An inner class thread on the remote peer sends a `ConcurrentHashMap` over an OOS.

When that arrives - and it does, ok - the receiving code continues, in a boolean-determined loop, to listen on the OIS for updates of that CCHM. These updates come from siblings of the one which sent the original CCHM (there is one serving sibling per receiving peer).  The `ObjectOutputStreams` these siblings use are taken from a visible `HashMap` of the siblings. The siblings don't care whether they are sending to a new member of the group, or to an existing one. The difference as to whether a peer is new or existing, is only known on the receiving peer side, where the original CCHM is received and used, and the code then continues waiting for updates on the same OIS. New peers which join have their details added to the remote's `Hashtable`, so the CCHM to be sent is one element larger every time it is sent to all the peers (the new one, plus the n existing).

But the existing peers do not receive the updated CCHM. Rather than filling my code with `System.out.println()` calls or stopping it crudely, what pitfalls have I likely overlooked to get in this mess?

Comment: Can you actually give some code please?

Answer (score 1):

See the specification for [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29)...

> Reset will disregard the state of any objects already written to the stream. The state is reset to be the same as a new ObjectOutputStream. The current point in the stream is marked as reset so the corresponding ObjectInputStream will be reset at the same point. Objects previously written to the stream will not be refered to as already being in the stream. They will be written to the stream again.

Comment: What can I say but ufff - was that ever an accurate and effective answer. Thank you sooo much!